# ReSharper function shows "Files still read-only"

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, resharper

When I try to "Remove Unused References" on some projects, resharper shows a window with a message:
Refactoring failed "Files still read-only"
Files are not read-only, I can edit them.
VS2013, with update 3.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Change a value to None for "Current source control plug-in:" combobox here Tools | Options | Source Control | Plugin Selection. It seems as if "Microsoft Git provider" is selected there now. And it is [a known issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-338404) due to a bug in "Microsoft Git provider" shipped with VS 2013.

[image]

[August 2022] Update for users of VS2019: If you have recently started experiencing this issue, please follow [this workaround](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-485369/Refactoring-failed-Files-still-read-only#focus=Comments-27-6352457.0-0).

Comment: Wow, still an issue in Visual Studio 2015 with Resharper 10, what's up with that?!

Comment: Yea I am having the same issue in vs 2015 everything has latest version and updates.

Comment: yep also fixed for VS2015 Community update3 v4.6.0138 + ReSharper Ultimate 2016.1.2

Comment: same issue and it was out and the blue. This was the solution!! thx

Comment: In Resharper 2021.2.1 this setting was in Environment\Performance Guide, then click the [Open Options] button

Answer (score 4):

Had this problem with Visual Studio 2019 today. Restarted Visual Studio and it worked.

Comment: Had the problem yesterday and today in VS2019. Restarting Visual Studio or my PC does not help.

Answer (score 2):

Today, I updated both Visual Studio 2019 and ReSharper to the latest versions, and this fixed the problem.

Update (08-Aug-2022): It's not working again.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this today. I was just in debug mode. I stopped debugging, and all was well in the world.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling Solution Wide Analysis, restarting Visual Studio and turning SWA on again did it for me. Just restarting Visual Studio or Windows did not help and I didn't want to tamper with any Git settings.

Answer (score 0):

Had the problem and uptated VS 2019 to the latest 16.11.18 and started working

Answer (score 0):

Disabling GIT extension resolved this problem for me.
My SWA was disabled all this time.
Updating VS also didn't help.